# EXC_BAD_ACCESS quey consulting Realm database with RealmSwift library retrieving Object from Database

Tags: swift, objective-c, realm

I designed a full class to manage Realm Database on my app. Every method seems to work fine with the same instance of Realm. But when I go to the query methods I get an EXC_BAD_ACCESS Error. For example lets take my method getLogin():

```
public func getLogin() -> Login {
    guard let realm = self.realm else {
         fatalError("Didnt find Realm instance")
    }
    let loginObjects: Results<Login> = realm.objects(Login.self)
    guard let loginObject: Login = loginObjects.first else { --- Thread1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS
         fatalError("Error getting Login object from Realm")
    }
    return objetoLogin
}
```

My Login object is defined in an independent class:

```
import Foundation
import RealmSwift

class Login : Object{
    @objc dynamic var cif : String = ""
    @objc dynamic var password : String = ""
    @objc dynamic var iosToken : String = ""
    @objc dynamic var iag_id : Int32 = 0
    @objc dynamic var iat_id : Int32 = 0
    convenience init(cif: String, password: String, iosToken: String) {
        self.init()
        self.cif = cif
        self.password = password
        self.iosToken = iosToken
        self.iag_id = 0
        self.iat_id = 0
    }
    
    override static func primaryKey() -> String? {
        return "cif"
    }
}
```

I tried controlling an error that's not working, since I never get to see any of the fatalErrors on the console. I made sure to define an instance of Realm that would be used in the entire app without leaving the instance. I made sure I have at least 1 Login object in the database when initiating the app. Maybe I got the syntax wrong for handling Objects in Realm.

I am using the following software versions:
Realm 10.39.1
RealmDatabase 13.10.1
-- Both imported by SwiftPackageManager --
Xcode 13.4
And building for iOS 12+

Comment: Why is this tagged with CoreData & MongoDB while you seem to use Realm?

Comment: @Larme Core data was obviously incorrect but Realm is actually called MongoDB Realm. Mongo bought Realm a few years ago and integrated it into their offerings. Realm is backed by MongoDB Atlas at the server level.

Comment: @MarMon. There are a number of issues with the code; first off it appears you're using Swift? If so, you really need to use the more modern Swift syntax to structure the Realm models and make calls. Secondly, that code should not even compile as this `return objetoLogin` is a syntax error and does not exist. Lastly, we don't know how your realm is formed `self.realm`. Please take a moment and review [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: @Jay Sorry, what do you mean by modern swift syntax? I am new to Swift developing and Realm also. This methods where built back in 2019. Currently I've been rewritting this app's clases. But I am stucked with Realm. I dont quite understand the database handling. I know how to handle java objects but these are completely different.
What would you recommend for me to start building a simple App in Swift using UIKIT and RealmSwift for storing 5 objects that get their values from Firebase and store it in local Realm. Where can I educate myself to be able to solve this?

Comment: The code syntax is ObjC and while there's nothing wrong with it, Swift syntax may be a bit easier, require less code and provide more compatibility. For example `@objc dynamic var password : String = ""` is replaced in Swift `@Persisted var password = ""`. The [Realm Swift SDK](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/realm/sdk/swift/) guide provides numerous code examples using Swift. Getting data from Firebase and storing in Realm goes beyond the scope of SO, but it can be done (we use both). However, I would suggest either using Realm or Firebase but not both as there may not be a reason to.

Comment: @Jay thank you so much for the info, I have to use both Firebase and Realm since the data I want to handle comes from a Firebase project that is shared by more Apps and I want the device to remember the data from Firebase whenever I log in the App. So I store it in Realm. I considered using SQLite also but the App was built with Realm initially.

Comment: Understood. Firebase does provide offline persistence in case you need it. As far as the code in the question goes, other than the Syntax error mentioned above, I copy and pasted your exact code into a project and it works correctly. No crashes. That leads me to believe the issue lies elsewhere in the project, probably how `realm` is defined or configured.